# How can I unwrap an array?

Tags: arrays, uitableview, swift3

I'm having an issue when unwrapping an array. I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly, please help:

This is my dictionary:

```
class NewsModel: NSObject {
    var data :NSArray = []
    var title :String = ""
    var urlImage: String = ""
    var link: String = ""
}
```

Here the Json Parse:

```
 let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: result as! Data, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
                if let parseJSON = json{
                    let newsModel = NewsModel()
                    let status = parseJSON["status"] as! Bool
                    if (status) {
                        let data = parseJSON["data"] as! NSArray
                        newsModel.data = data
                        storeProtocols[Actions.getNews]?.onSuccess(type, result: newsModel)
                    } else {
                        let error = parseJSON["error"] as! NSDictionary
                        storeProtocols[Actions.getNews]?.onError(type, error: error)
                    }
                }
```

Finally I'm trying to show my array in a UITableView:

```
var newsModel = NewsModel()

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let notifications = self.newsModel.data.count
        return notifications
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let notifications = self.newsModel.data[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.text = String(describing: (notifications as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "title"))
        return cell   
    }
```

But my issue is that I'm obtaining the "Optional" legend before the value of the array, like this:

[TableView Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkfzL.png)

Comment: Also, the value for the key `"title"` is already a string. There's no reason to pass that into `String(describing:)`. Just assign it directly to `cell.textLabel!.text`.

Comment: This is kind of a mess, I can help you clean it up if you provide more information on what data is on NewsModel

Comment: This is the data on NewsModel: {
  "status": true,
  "data": [
    {
      "title": "Nuevo evento para los mas pequeños",
      "urlImage": "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/48/bd/3f/48bd3f6e928d7cb4b8d499cb0f96b8a8.jpg",
      "link": "http://...."
    }
  ]
}

Comment: So data is an array of dictionaries?

Comment: Yes it is, that's the reason why I declared it as a NSDictionary

Comment: Why an `NSDictionary`, and not a Swift `Dictionary`?

Comment: Because the data may change in the future, that's why

Comment: That explains why it should be a dictionary of some kind, but it doesn't explain why it's an `NSDictionary` and not a regular Swift `Dictionary`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting an **Optional** `String` is that `(notifications as! NSDictionary).value(forKey: "title")`:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    /* Return the result of sending -objectForKey: to the receiver.
    */
    open func value(forKey key: String) -> Any?
}
```

Returns an **Optional** `Any` which it will be an **Optional** `String` for your particular case.

---

So you need to unwrap the **Optional** `String` to get a `String`, there are many ways to unwrap but the safest one is **Optional unwrapping.**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = UITableViewCell()
  let notifications = self.newsModel.data[indexPath.row]

  if let dictionary = notifications as? NSDictionary {
    if let title = dictionary.value(forKey: "title") as? String {
      cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
  }

  return cell
}
```

When you have time, you can read a little bit about **Optionals**, I have created a post about it: https://medium.com/@wilson.balderrama/what-are-optionals-in-swift-3-b669ca4c2f12#.rb76h4r9k